# How to create histogram of sales depending on day of week in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series, histogram

I have DataFrame in Python Pandas like below:

```
day_of_week| sales
-----------|------
4          | 140
6          | 500
3          | 234
...        | ...
```

Create histogram of sales depending on day of week. To be hones I do not understand how to make such a histogram and how to interpret the results because I don't understand what it is supposed to represent ?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the DataFrame looks like this. You can draw a bar plot to visualize the sales for each day.

```
days_of_week=[1,2,3,4,6,7,5]
sales_per_day = [140,43,23,45,67,89,700]
df=pd.DataFrame({"days_of_week":days_of_week,"sales_per_day":sales_per_day})
# Added red trend line
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.bar(df.days_of_week,df.sales_per_day)
plt.plot(df.days_of_week,df.sales_per_day,color="red")
plt.show()
```

Comment: could you add red trend line ? to this plot

Comment: hmmm but it is not a histogram :/  I need histogram but I do not understand idea of plot histogram on sales data by day

Comment: A histogram is used to see the frequency distribution of the dataset. If you have a large dataset and you want to know which day of the week (2,6,4 etc) had the maximum number of orders then you can use hist plots to visualize the results.

Comment: why do you want to use a histogram anyway? State your problem

Comment: Ahsan Nawaz - Because my task is to use histogram, could you suggest how to build this histogram to know which day of the week (2,6,4 etc) had the maximum number of orders then you can use hist plots to visualize the results ?

Comment: I have added the red trend line in my modified answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245229/discussion-between-ahsan-nawaz-and-ratus111).